# Saving UIBezierPaths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibezierpath

Is it possible to save lots of UIBezierPaths? If so, how can it be done? I've tried putting them all into an NSMutableArray (and NSMutableDictionary) and then saving that array/dictionary to NSUserDefaults but I get this warning:

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
"<UIBezierPath: 0x20b9ca10>",
"<UIBezierPath: 0x20a1dbf0>",
"<UIBezierPath: 0x20b9e550>",
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code

```
-(void)saveData :(NSMutableArray *)dataArray;
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                                stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:
     dataArray toFile:dataFilePath];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)loadData;
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                                stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    // Check if the file already exists
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath])
    {
        NSMutableArray *dataArray;

        dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                     unarchiveObjectWithFile: dataFilePath];

        return dataArray;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Should work fine, I tested this saving BezierPath and seems to work fine. I create a class called archiving which handles saving and loading arrays and dictionaries to and from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that archives/unarchives the UIBezierPath directly:

```
- (NSURL *)documentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (void)archivePath:(UIBezierPath*)bPath withName:(NSString *)archiveName
{
    NSString *savePath = [[[self documentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:archiveName] path];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:bPath toFile:savePath];
}

- (UIBezierPath *)unarchivePathWithName:(NSString *)archiveName
{
    return (UIBezierPath *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[[self documentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:archiveName] path]];
}
```

I'm not doing any error checking or verifying that the file exists, but this works if you're sure there's a file there. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
UIBezierPath *bez = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 100)];
[bez appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)]];
[self archivePath:bez withName:@"path.archive"];
UIBezierPath *bez2 = [self unarchivePathWithName:@"path.archive"];
```